# MS Access Enter Paramater Value dialogue

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am getting a strange 'Enter Parameter Value' request from Access. This query ran just fine and then the next day I have this problem. I cannot see why though.

It wants me to enter Query1.hole_id.

```
SELECT assay.*
FROM assay 
INNER JOIN collar 
ON assay.hole_id=collar.hole_id
WHERE collar.section="ERC" AND collar.level="645";
```

[Enter Parameter Value dialogue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04DIL.png)

Comment: Try see: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/why-does-access-want-me-to-enter-a-parameter-value-0e71a1dd-e498-49a1-9e2e-356538d226ff

Comment: Yes I did, but as you can see I have not used hole_id in that way. Where does Query1 even come from? Why did the query run fine the day before.

Comment: Have you truly gone through the solutions in the link to no avail? Because the support link is directly targeted towards what you are experiencing. Try to look at each step.

Comment: Yes I have. It specifically starts with "...note the identifier or expression that's listed in the dialog box." First problem - this doesn't make sense. Then it entirely deals with expressions. There are no expressions anywhere in this dB. It's incredibly simple. Just a query.

Comment: And following on from the below suggestion I tried entering a valid hole_id that exists in ASSAY. I get 0 rows returned.

Comment: Are `assay` and `collar` tables or queries? If the latter, do they use `Query1` somewhere (perhaps in a subquery)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is truly annoying. There is nothing wrong with my query. There was something wrong with Access. I copied and pasted my exact query into a new fresh one and it worked just fine. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

try to do like this

Solution 1:

```
SELECT assay.*
FROM assay 
INNER JOIN collar 
ON assay.[hole_id]=collar.[hole_id]
WHERE collar.[section]="ERC" AND collar.[level]=645;
```

above stated answer didn't work for you than try the second one

Solution 2:

```
SELECT assay.*
FROM assay INNER JOIN collar ON assay.[hole_id] = collar.[hole_id]
WHERE (((collar.section)="ERC") AND ((collar.level)=645));
```

I have run this query and its work for me.

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. Thanks though.

Comment: Thank you. You're right. The query is fine. See below. Thanks for your time!